# Can we make a db call to set all the initial values inside a constructor?

Tags: java, spring

```
// This is my LoginController
 public String login() throws InvoiceException{
        //HttpSession session ; 
        String email = this.getEmail();
        String password = this.getPassword();
        if(loginService.authenticateLogin(email, password) == true){
        System.out.println("Login Successful");
        customer = loginService.getCustomerBean(email);
        //Creating a new Session

        /*session = (HttpSession) sessionManager.getSession("CustomerInfo");
        session.setAttribute("CustomerId",customer.getCustomerId());
        session.setAttribute("email", customer.getEmail());
        session.setAttribute("CustomerName", customer.getFirstName());

        sessionManager.setSession("CustomerInfo", session);*/
        sessionManager.setSession("CustomerId", customer.getCustomerId());
        sessionManager.setSession("email", customer.getEmail());
        sessionManager.setSession("CustomerName", customer.getFirstName());
        return "ProfilePage";
    }
    else{
        setErrorMessage("Bad Username/Password");
    return "LoginOrRegister";
    }
}
```

/*This is my Profile page Controller's contructor. profileService autowired at beginning during instance variable declaration part of the class.
sessionManager is an instance of class SessionManager which contains methods for get and set sessions for session Tracking in JSF.

i want to display the profile page of the user using with all his/her values that are stored in DB. But when spring is instantiating beans to inject, all these values will be set to null initially isnt it? how do i set these inital values ? also the service class isnt gettng instantiated which is autowired.

```
public ProfilePageController(){
    sessionManager = new SessionManager();
    customerId = (Integer) sessionManager.getSession("CustomerId");
    email = (String) sessionManager.getSession("email");
    firstName = (String) sessionManager.getSession("CustomerName");

    try {
        customer = profileService.getCustomerBean(customerId);
    } catch (InvoiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
    this.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
    this.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
    this.setPassword(customer.getPassword());
    this.setCity(customer.getCity());
    this.setState(customer.getState());
    this.setCountry(customer.getCountry());
    this.setPhoneNumber(customer.getPhoneNumber());
    this.setGender(customer.getGender());
    this.setZipCode(customer.getZipCode());
    this.setCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId());
}
```

Comment: Yes, does your code not working?

Comment: No its working... autowiring is not working..

Comment: My major concern was when Injection happens, customerId will be null and hence no object will be retrieved from the DB. so how do i solve that too @Dr.Stitch

Comment: can't you pass the id to your controller? via constructor parameter?

Answer (score 0):

That can't possibly work. Put yourself in Spring's shoes. You need to create a ProfilePageController and autowire some of its fields. How can you do that?

Well, in order to set a field in an object, you need that object, right. So you need to first create the object. How can you create an object? By calling its constructor, right?

But your constructor tries to use the field, and that field will only be autowired after the constructor has been called. So you get a NullPointerException.

There are several solutions (that can be combined)

- use constructor injection rather than field injection. This is a good idea in general: it makes testing easier, and makes the dependencies clearer
- do your initialization work inside a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. ill surely try this and revert back @JB Nizet

Comment: Well, the thing is now i put all my code inside a @PostContruct method... The method takes an Id from session and using the id retrieves relevant information from DB. but since session has no values during Injection and after, it throws a null pointer exception. i need the values from Db moment the webpage is opened.. where do i write the code for retrieval ?

Comment: In the RequestMapping method displaying the profile page. The controller should be stateless.

Comment: actually i'm using JSF. there is no requestMapping